# How change button background twice at runtime in widget?

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget, and contain some button. The buttons label string come from AsyncHTTPTask.
I would change the button background is black before start internet connection and then receive data change button BG to green. The exampe doesn't work. I don't see black status, just finished green status.

```
        remoteViews.setInt(
                    context.getResources().getIdentifier("widget_button" + i, "id", context.getPackageName()),
                    "setBackgroundResource",
                    R.drawable.button_draw_black_gradient
                    );
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
        try {
            jsonStr = new AsyncHTTPTask().execute(SURL).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ....
        remoteViews.setInt(
                    context.getResources().getIdentifier("widget_button" + i, "id", context.getPackageName()),
                    "setBackgroundResource",
                    R.drawable.button_draw_green_gradient
                    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem now.
This part make force upadte:

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,FooBar.class);
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to request the view's layout and manually refresh the view by calling `invalidate` :

```
    remoteViews.requestLayout();
    remoteViews.setInt(
                context.getResources().getIdentifier("widget_button" + i, "id", context.getPackageName()),
                "setBackgroundResource",
                R.drawable.button_draw_black_gradient
                );
    remoteViews.invalidate();
```

And i think there is something wrong with your code. You should change the button to green when `AsyncTask` has **finished** its task.

So move this code to the `onPost` :

```
    remoteViews.requestLayout();
    remoteViews.setInt(
                context.getResources().getIdentifier("widget_button" + i, "id", context.getPackageName()),
                "setBackgroundResource",
                R.drawable.button_draw_green_gradient
                );
    remoteViews.invalidate();
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( "The method invalidate() is undefined for the type RemoteViews"

View have invalidate method, but remoteView haven't invalidate method.